# How can I opt out of election announcement messages?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderator-election

I would like my message/inbox/notification count to not highlight / increment when an election starts. I suspect that I can't do that if I'm getting the message, so I'd like to opt out of the messages.

Comment: This happens **rarely**. Is it that big a deal to ignore the 2 or 3 messages per year?

Comment: You're likely to get more notifications from just this post than you'll get over the next several years of election notifications.

Comment: uncle sam is disappoint.

Comment: And even if you could ignore the notifications the elections themselves are going to be prominent on the site during their course.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipp-Ex

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Is this a bad question, or just a disliked question?

Comment: It's a feature request @JoshuaDance, in which case the "Voting is different" section applies: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Thanks Bart. Still rookie on MSO. Seems painful to suggest a feature no one likes. :)

Comment: Please, no user control over notifications. Then you'll see questions like "Why don't I get a notification about XXXX?!?!" The cost:benefit of this feature is too extremely low.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 2 or 3 per year? I see one (or more) per site per year, and I'm on a lot more than 3 SE sites.

Comment: @Servy I want to keep getting notifications for posts.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't visit many of those sites nearly often enough to be bothered by the prominent election information on the site. I see the notifications when I'm NOT going to that specific site.

Comment: @Sparr: your level of participation across the network is indeed impressive. There are not many people that *have* that many of accounts over 200 points; it appears you have a problem that *very* few people actually have.

Comment: @Sparr: but for most sites, elections are not that frequent. Perhaps there is a current storm of elections as the SE network has been growing aggressively of late with the success of Area 51 swelling the ranks, and there are many sites graduating now? The number of elections should even out if that is the case.

Comment: @Sparr: the fact that you have 23 accounts > 200, a further 23 > 101 could have been relevant to your feature request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 101 is the starting reputation for a linked account, isn't it? There's nothing special about 101.

Comment: @Sparr: an account with *just* the association bonus can still be deleted.

Comment: three more election notifications since my last post here. @MartijnPieters

(if the election notifications shouldn't bother me, these tags shouldn't bother you, right? (yes, I know this is petty, but that's the most straightforward response to this annoyance that I can think of))

Comment: @Servy it's been 16 months. I think I've gotten about 5x as many election notifications as notifications about this question (comments and answers). I come here to make this comment after getting 3 more election notifications this week.

Comment: @MartijnPieters were you suggesting that I could delete some of my accounts to get fewer such notices?

Comment: so many more notifications :(

Comment: The quantity of the notifications isn't really the issue. Rather the fact that some of us think that the election process is a farce and would rather not be reminded of it at all.  It's a distraction from what we come here for, which is to be better at our day jobs.  Therefore, I don't see it as unreasonable to request the ability to OPT OUT of a notification for an election that is OPTIONAL in the first place.  Stating that it's only a few times a year is the same as stating that we have no legitimate reason to not want these, which is a bit condescending imo.

Comment: Now I'm getting THREE notifications per election. Nomination, Primary, and Election. This is getting ridiculous.

Comment: +1 this is incredibly annoying.  Classic example of those in power blinded by it.

Answer (score 16):

There's currently no way to toggle the types of notifications that you receive because there really hasn't been a need for it yet - there just aren't that many triggers for them. If we got to the point that we actually *did* need them, then we'd probably want to sanity-check the reasons that we're lighting up that icon. Competing platforms have granular notification management settings with around a *hundred* different knobs to turn, that's not us :)

Don't at all feel obligated to participate in an election if you don't want to - and it's fine if you don't. There are folks that just aren't at *all* interested in the process and don't want to meddle - that's understandable. It's okay if you just ignore the notification.

Comment: I get an election notification something like half of the days that I visit SE. It's really annoying. I can only imagine how much so it is for people who use more SE sites.

Comment: I cannot imagine many people with more active accounts than you have!

Comment: @MartijnPieters is it not expected that over time more users will have more accounts? I can easily see SE having tens of thousands of users with linked accounts on a hundred sites.

Comment: That may be, I'm sure the team will have to rethink a number of things if that time comes. Until then, you may well be a very small minority and that weighs against a feature request when there are limited resources to implement new features.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in that I also have Sparr's problem. I only have 30 accounts, not 64, but yeah, it's pretty irritating. A constant stream of spam in my notifications.

Comment: Another election notification today, after two last week. Notifications for me, notifications for you! :)

Comment: Plenty more notifications in the last six months. Another one today reminded me to come comment here again.

Comment: Still getting these announcements every week or two.

Comment: Two more today! Hooray. :/

Comment: "there really hasn't been a need for it" - If by "a need," you mean, it doesn't bother the people in charge of deciding how to design the site, then sure... If you stop for half a second to think how biased that statement is and thus how meaningless your analysis is, you might rethink it.  OP has a very valid point, and plenty of us are very bothered by this.

Comment: @Apollys Can you take a minute and re-read what you just typed out loud? Can you understand that, to me, you just came running at me arms in the air screaming over something I haven't visited since 2014? Do you understand how hostile and condescending what you just wrote sounds?

Comment: @TimPost the fact that we aren't bothering you about this every time it bothers us is a favor.
I've gotten seven election notifications in the past two weeks. That's about half my total notifications. It's basically a crapshoot whether I'm going to have anything to read/do when I see a new notification here, to the point that I don't even check sometimes.

Comment: @Sparr I'll bring the topic up again. There are _really_ compelling reasons to try and push the turnout for elections even higher, because even with record participation, the turnout is hardly representative. I think, then, this is more of a question of "what are better ways to get folks to participate in elections?" We could put a toggle in for this but the blocker there is the fear that we'd lower turnout even more, so it's probably time to revisit again. Alright, I'll bring it up internally and see if we can get a conversation going here.

Comment: @TimPost what if notifications for elections only appeared when visiting the site in question? Or at least only activated the red notification counter? I haven't visited most of the sites in question in years. Yes, it might lower turnout, but do you really want someone like me voting in one of those elections?

Comment: @Sparr The answer is, most certainly, yes. We want all users that _can_ vote to be able to say that they knew an election was happening, and that they found no barriers to participating. We're going to begin a study right now to determine if it's not really a notification, but a barrier to participation issue (up to and including "I couldn't find anyone to identify with to vote for"). This is going to take a while but it's worth re-examining the whole system.