# Can we revisit the decision not to allow muting election notifications?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, moderator-election

This question has already been asked a few times: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364847/can-i-disable-election-notifications) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250148/how-can-i-opt-out-of-election-announcement-messages).

However, I don't feel that it should be closed as a dupe, because the prevailing mood in the comments on the above-linked questions seems to be "if this ever becomes a serious problem, we can reconsider our decision not to allow the functionality".

I think that time has come -- the *vast majority* of my notifications are election-related. I think the same is probably true for a lot of casual users of the site who don't post often enough to have a lot of non-election notifications.

This example is representative: out of my last six notifications, five have been election-related. I don't know anything about the moderator candidates on all these random small sites that I never use anymore, so that means my last five notifications have been entirely useless. Every time I see one, it just makes me irritated and annoyed, and less likely to bother clicking the notification jewel in the future (which will prevent me from seeing actual comments and replies).

[image]

Comment: 5 Election notifications in a timespan of 7 months. How inactive are you on SE that that's all you're getting?

Comment: If that frequency of notifications is a problem, and it becomes "the vast majority of your notifications"... I guess the better solution is simply to log-out? After a quick glance at your profile, it looks like you have been pretty much inactive for the last couple of years. Why do you log-in at all, if not to receive some sort of notification?

Comment: I'm probably more active than the vast majority of SE users, for whom the site is treated as read-only. Anyway, if "users below a certain activity threshold should just log out" is the consensus, then, sure, I can do that. I sort of doubt encouraging marginal users to log out is actually desired by SE's product teams, though.

BTW, there are reasons to log in other than receiving notifications; for example, because I am following certain tags.

Comment: You haven't been active on SE [since april of this year](https://stackexchange.com/users/87591/brennan-vincent?tab=activity)...

Comment: "it just makes me irritated and annoyed" - well, don't ignore that signal. Recognise it as *your* problem to solve and work on it.

Comment: @StephenRauch It's not a duplicate. The OP specifically mentioned that they saw that question (which is [status-declined]) and wants the decision of declining it to be revisited.

Comment: It is exceedingly trivial to just... ignore them by not looking at them.

Comment: @BrennanVincent You can permanently dismiss the "notification jewel" by clicking on the notifications icon (until you receive more notifications). I don't see a serious problem with something that can be handled with a single click.

Comment: Would using a bot that automatically reads election notifications be an option?

Answer (score 7):

> *"if this ever becomes a serious problem, we can reconsider our decision not to allow the functionality"*

I think this is still a valid conclusion.

You've gotten 5 election notifications in a timespan of ~7 months. That means there's roughly 42 days between each notification, on average.

That, in no way, qualifies as a serious problem, or a significant distraction.

---

As you describe, the problem is the ratio of election notifications vs other notifications.

The problem there is that there's just [no other activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/87591/brennan-vincent?tab=activity) on your account during those past 4 months, so what can you expect?

> [image]

Comment: The issue is not the _frequency_, but the fraction of total notifications.

When only a small fraction of notifications is actually relevant to me, the notifications jewel is useless.

Comment: There's no other activity on your account to notify you about... What'd you expect, @BrennanVincent?